# Rails: finding records where attribute includes some value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, include, where-clause

I have a "Stores" model that contains various locations.  Among the attributes for each store is the the "brands" that is carries.

Example: Store1, brands: "Nike, Adidas, Polo"; Store2, brands: "Jcrew, Polo"

I want to be able to select all stores where brand contains "Adidas" (may also contain other brands)

Something along the lines of:

```
@search = Stores.where(brands: params[:brand])
```

but need it to be

```
@search = Stores.where(brands.include? params[:brand])
```

which clearly doesn't work

What's the best way to deal with this?

Comment: `brands` seems to be a string. Is that right?

Comment: correct.  "Nike, Adidas, Polo" etc

Comment: Part of the problem may be that this is not the best way to track brands. Brands should be normalized into their own table with an associated join table. Proper architecture would obviate this entire question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `brands` is a string and params[:brand] contains a single brand name, you can use MySQL's LIKE function:

```
@search = Stores.where(['BRANDS LIKE ?', "%#{params[:brand]}%"])
```

Answer (score -3):

You can do this with the following statement.

```
@search = Stores.where("brands = ?", params[:brand])
```

A similar example is given in Listing 11.43 of the [Hardtl rails tutorial](http://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users#sec-the_new_status_feed)

You should also note that rails models generally are meant to have singular names, i.e. Store instead of Stores.

Comment: This does exactly the same as `where(brands: params[:brand])`